# c++ template: 'constexpr auto xx' can't work in c++11

Tags: c++, templates

this code can work in c++17, but I get error in c++11.

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto is_ref_counted_directly = !std::is_same<int, T>::value;
```

Could you give me some help, thanks.
my env: gcc 4.8.5, c++11.

Comment: Why the "c" tag? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `c11` `c17` doesn't have template afaict. do you mean `c++11` `c++17`?

Comment: There is no way this will work with any version of C: you are using C++ concepts like classes, templates and namespaces which simply do not exist in C. [C code is *mostly* C++ compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) but the other way is not the case.

Comment: thanks for your reminder, I will modify this question

Answer (score 0):

[Variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) need at least `c++14`, so it would not work in `c++11`

---

gcc 4.8.5 [seems not support `c++14`](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) btw

Comment: thanks for your reply, I try to use a function template with a static local variable, which return this variable.